# Is it possible to make webview responsive in cardview or recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context mContext;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    Button start;
   // TextView textView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.0.103:3001", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(response);
                            for(int i = 0; i < response.length();i++){

                                JSONObject json_res = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                RecyclerAdapter.embed_html.add(json_res.getString("v.embed_html"));

                            }

                        //Recycler View Setup
                        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println(e);                        }
                    }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener(){
                        @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                                    System.out.println(error);
                        }
                }
                );
               requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import newsee.novasyslabs.com.nodefetch.Others.CircularTransform;

import com.squareup.picasso.MemoryPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    public static ArrayList <String> embed_html = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        WebView webView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.webView = (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.web);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_card, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            holder.webView.loadData(embed_html.get(position), "text/html", "utf-8");

        }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return embed_html.size();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="newsee.novasyslabs.com.nodefetch.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Request"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/appBarLayout"
        />


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

layout_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I'm trying to set my webview in cardview and it is working fine but the I'm facing that when I run on 5.5 inch phone then it goes out of the screen and when i run my code on tablet it cover the whole screen.
I want it to be like. It fit on that card with wrap_content height and and fill the parent when I run app on any of the device. whether Tab or Mobile.
Please help me I m new to android.
Thanks in Advance!!!

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7uaY.jpg)

Comment: I think your `Webview` is of the within the screen size. The content displayed inside the webview is going out of the screen. You cant do anything about it unless you have control over the website.

Comment: actually i am just passing the video link only.

Comment: Is their any option which will help me to do what i want.

Comment: can you show an image of `Show layout bounds` enabled in developer on the small phone and a sample of html your are setting ?

Comment: click here to see image click on the image @Panther